# Postgresql: Cannot insert to path field using EclipseLink

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipselink, converters

I have a java app running in JBoss that uses EclipseLink to persist to a Postgres database. I've added a field with a 'path' datatype to one of the tables but I keep getting exceptions when I try to insert data.

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table_name
(
    item_id    uuid NOT NULL,
    item_path  path NOT NULL
)
```

The java entity is representing the item_path field as a List object, and I'm using a converter to map from the List object to a PGpath object:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.Converter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;
import org.postgresql.geometric.PGpath;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import static java.sql.Types.OTHER;

public class PgPathConverter implements Converter
{
    @Override
    public boolean isMutable ()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Point> convertDataValueToObjectValue (Object value, Session session)
    {
        // Code that converts PGpath to List<Point>
    }

    @Override
    public PGpath convertObjectValueToDataValue (Object value, Session session)
    {
        // Code that converts List<Point> to PGpath
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize (DatabaseMapping mapping, Session session)
    {
        mapping.getField ().setSqlType (OTHER);
    }
}
```

The entity class is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table (
    name           = "table_name",
    schema         = "schema"
)
@Converter (
    name           = "path",
    converterClass = PgPathConverter.class
)
public class TableName
{
    public TableName () {}
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column (name = "item_path")
    @Convert ("path")
    private List<Point> m_ItemPath;

    @Id
    @Column (
        name     = "item_id",
        unique   = true,
        nullable = false
    )
    private UUID        m_ItemId;

    public UUID getItemId ()
    {
        return m_ItemId;
    }

    public List<Point> getItemPath ()
    {
        return m_InkPath;
    }

    public void setItemId (UUID itemId)
    {
        m_ItemId = itemId;
    }

    public void setInkPath (List<Point> itemPath)
    {
         m_ItemPath = itemPath;
    }
}
```

Finally, here's the exception I get when I call `EntityManager.persist (entity)`:

```
18:10:33,789 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.postgresql.geometric.PGpath. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO schema.table_name (item_id, item_path) VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
18:10:33,789 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component TableNameRepository for method public void com.mycompany.myproject.data.Repository.flush() throws javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException,javax.persistence.PersistenceException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.postgresql.geometric.PGpath. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO schema.table_name (item_id, item_path VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:138) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:317) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:214) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
```

I've manually entered some data into table to see if I could successfully pull data from the table using EclipseLink. Now the convertDataValueToObjectValue method in my Converter throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.geometric.PGpath cannot be cast to org.postgresql.geometric.PGpath
```

Comment: I've edited my question by adding the exception that is being thrown when I try to pull data from table with EclipseLink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was a problem with how I had configured my application in JBoss. I had multiple copies of the jdbc driver jar, one in the deployed EAR file and one in the JBoss container. This was causing confusion because each jar was being loaded by a separate ClassLoader. Java identifies the class by its full name AND the ClassLoader.

Since I had already added the driver jar as a module to the JBoss server, I needed to remove the driver jar from the deployed EAR and set a dependency to the module that was in the JBoss server.

This link has some more details: https://community.jboss.org/message/862434